# Is there a way to make a sale price null if the value is 0 wooCommerce including product variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a sheet that is exported from my customers Back end stock system.

It includes sale price and retail price. The problem is for the sale pricing if there is no price they are using "0" as the value which in turn means that when the product update runs the product essentially becomes free

I have tried a few options from here. This one seemed to work the best

```php
add_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'check_sale_price', 40 );
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_sale_price', 40 );
function check_sale_price() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->sale_price == '0' ) {
        $price = $product->regular_price;
        $product->sale_price = $price;
        $product->price = $price;
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->get_results( 'UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='.$price.' WHERE meta_key="_sale_price" AND post_id='.$product->id, OBJECT );
        $wpdb->get_results( 'UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='.$price.' WHERE meta_key="_price" AND post_id='.$product->id, OBJECT );
    }
}
```

But this did not update all my variable products only simple products

It would be great if this code could also update product sale pricing that is "0" in product variations as well

Comment: would suggest to update sale price only if greater then 0 else donot execute this update query.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Amol, the only problem is, this script is not updating product variations, only simple products. even if I change to >0

Comment: normal price with meta_key as _regular_price and meta_value as  $price 
apart form this three more entries .
meta_key as _sale_price and meta_value as  $saleprice ( here the post_id field is after you conver to variation type post say 5857) .
meta_key as _price and meta_value as  $price ( here the post_id field is after you conver to variation type post say 5857) .
meta_key as _price and meta_value as  $price  ( here the post_id field is of original post say 5856) .

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works with query you can use it in your function.

Try this (where, `$price = "set you price"` , `$product->id = "product id"`)

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta as pm
    JOIN  wp_postmeta as pm2 ON pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
    SET pm.meta_value = ( $price )
    WHERE pm.meta_key LIKE '_sale_price'
      AND pm2.meta_key LIKE '_price'
      AND pm.post_id IN
        ( SELECT p2.ID
         FROM wp_posts AS p
         JOIN wp_posts AS p2 ON p2.post_parent = p.ID
         WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
           AND p.post_status = 'publish'
           AND p.ID = $product->id
           AND p2.post_type = 'product_variation'
           AND p2.post_status = 'publish' );
```

Comment: Hi there sorry to be a n00b but I don't really know how to add a query into a function, but thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this for update product price

```
    add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_sale_price', 40 );
function check_sale_price() {
global $product;
//update product price 
if ( $product->get_sale_price() == '0' ) {
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $product->set_sale_price($price); 
        $product->set_price($price); 
        $product->save(); 
}
}
```

Comment: hi there, I tried this but it didn't seem to do anything, :(. thank you for your help though !

Comment: Sorry for that, But this a variation product, I will you code.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_sale_price', 40 );
function check_sale_price() {
    global $product;
    //update product price 
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach($available_variations as $variation ){
        $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
        $_product = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);

        if ( $product->get_sale_price() == '0' ) {
                $price = $_product->get_price();
                $_product->set_sale_price($price); 
                $_product->set_price($price); 
                $_product->save(); 
        }
    }
    $product->save(); 
}
```